# Pivot a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, pivot

I'm kinda new to using `pivot`.  How can I pivot this record from this:

```
P1AVERAGE    P2AVERAGE    P3AVERAGE   -> column name
1.25         1.50         1.75
```

to this:

```
AVERAGENAME    AVERAGESCORE
p1Average      1.25
p2Average      1.50
p3Average      1.75
```

I'm using both SQL Server and MS Access 2007.

Comment: Are you going to run the query in SQL Server or MS Access?  The syntax will not be the same.

Comment: ill be using it on both SQL Server and access.

Answer (score 7):

What are you trying to do is `UNPIVOT` not `PIVOT`, which is making the columns back into rows, it is the opposite of pivot.

**For SQL Server**, use the [`UNPIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) table operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename AS t
UNPIVOT
(
  AVERAGESCORE
  FOR plaveragename IN([P1AVERAGE], [P2AVERAGE], [P3AVERAGE])
) AS u;
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72378/1)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the following query in both SQL Server and MS Access. The UNION ALL takes the columns and converts the values into multiple rows:

```
select 'P1AVERAGE' as AverageName, P1AVERAGE as AverageScore
from yourtable
union all
select 'P2AVERAGE' as AverageName, P2AVERAGE as AverageScore
from yourtable
union all
select 'P3AVERAGE' as AverageName, P3AVERAGE as AverageScore
from yourtable
```